# React Native useEffect Hooks and React Navigation setParams doesn't update on loading

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-navigation, use-effect

How come my React Navigation setParams doesn't update data on component mounted?

```
const NewScreen = props => {
  const [extraInfo, setExtraInfo] = useState({
    title: '',
    description: '',
  });
  const [mediaArray, setMediaArray] = useState(null);
  const [someData, setSomeData] = useState({});

  const grabData = useCallback(() => {
    return axios
      .get('url')
      .then(res => {
        /* does some data grabbing for setSomeData and setMediaArray */

        setSomeData({
          data1,
          data2,
          data3,
        });
        setMediaArray(media);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('axios catch err', err));
  }, []);

  /* ... more data grabbing for extraInfo */

  useEffect(() => {
    grabData();
    props.navigation.setParams({
      mutate: props.mutate,
      title: extraInfo.title,
      description: extraInfo.description,
      newDataForAray: mediaArray,
      ...someData,
    });
  }, [grabData]);

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.keyboardView}>
      ...
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

NewScreen.navigationOptions = props => {
  const {mutate, title, description, newDataForAray} = props.navigation.state.params;
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    mutate({
      variables: {
        title,
        description,
      },
    });
  };
  return {
    headerRight: () => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => handleSubmit()}
        style={{marginRight: 10}}>
        <Text>Done</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  };
};

const mutation = gql`
  mutation someMutation(
    ...
  ) {
    ...
  }
`;

export default graphql(mutation)(withNavigation(NewScreen));
```

So on loading, I'm able to get data through `axios`. But when component mounts, the data in `prop.navigation.setParams` doesn't get populated. If I add `someData, mediaArray or extraInfo`, into the array of the useEffect callback, it will infinitely loop, rerendering my component, but the data in `navigation.state` will finally populate.

I want to be able to pass the values into navigation state so I can use it in the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current setup, `grabData` is going to pull your data but won't refresh `someData`, `mediaArray`, etc until the next render. But, your next render won't run since your useEffect's dependency array won't trigger.

You could use two `useEffects` with one reserved for `grabData` and other for `props.nav`. Better yet, update `props.nav` within `grabData`.

---

update reflecting comment

Media or somedata value doesn't change immediately. Thus, reference the same media  or somedata pulled by your api to your setParams

```
 const grabData = useCallback(() =>
  axios
  .get('url')
  .then(res => {
    /* does some data grabbing for setSomeData and setMediaArray */

    const someData = {
      data1,
      data2,
      data3,
    };
    setSomeData(someData);
    setMediaArray(media);
    const paramsTest = {
       mutate: props.mutate,
       title: extraInfo.title,
       description: extraInfo.description,
       newDataForAray: media,
       ...someData,
     };
     console.log({ paramsTest }); // used to confirm values provided to nav
     props.navigation.setParams(paramsTest);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('axios catch err', err)), [props.navigation.setParams]);
```

Comment: I tried inserting `props.navigation.setParams` right under the `setMediaArray(media);` line, but it sitll doesn't update the state parameters

Comment: @hellomello It depends on what you're supplying. I updated answer to reflect what it should be. Use the console.log to confirm the appropriate values are provided to props.nav . If it is and it still doesn't work, then its some other issue.

Comment: this method didn't work. It didn't log out the values, and if I provide `props.navigation.setParams` in the array, it just rerenders infinitely. I had to use a separate useEffect for the params.